# How to create multiple soft links to one file?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, symbolic-link

How would I go about creating a symlink that creates multiple links to one file?

I would like `~/Desktop/foo.txt` to "appear" in multiple locations; and the following doesn't work:

```
ln -s ~/Desktop/foo.txt /location/one /location/two
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ln.1.html) -- you can only specify one destination. You'll have to loop:

```
for destination in /location/one /location/two ...; do
    ln -s ~/Desktop/foo "$destination"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, in order to copy .gpl colour palettes into the appropriate GIMP, Inkscape and LibreOffice directories I did this:

```
read -e -p "Enter filename: " file

for destination in ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/config/ ~/.config/inkscape/palettes/ ~/.gimp-2.8/palettes/ ...; do
    ln --symbolic --backup --force "$file" "$destination"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Relatively simple python one-liner can do the job:

```
$ python -c 'import sys,os;map(lambda x:os.symlink(sys.argv[1],x),sys.argv[2:])' ~/input.txt ~/Desktop/input.txt ~/Pictures/input.txt
$ ls -l ~/Desktop/input.txt                                                                                              
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xieerqi xieerqi 23 2月   4 19:10 /home/xieerqi/Desktop/input.txt -> /home/xieerqi/input.txt
```

The way this works is simple. We use `sys` module for processing command-line arguments, and use `symlink()` function from `os`  module. The `map()` function essentially is used as replacement for the `for` loop, which takes a function and list as argument. Here, the function is `lambda x:os.symlink(sys.argv[1],x)`, and it will be executed for each item in `sys.argv[2:]` list.

Note, `~/input.txt` is original file (referred to as `sys.argv[1]` , second command-line argument ), and `~/Desktop/input.txt` and `~/Pictures/input.txt` are resulting symlinks. They are arguments 2 and 3, thus we use `sys.argv[2:]` list slice starting from 3rd item till the end of list. You may be wondering , well , where is the first argument. That's `-c` flag.

A script form of the same thing would be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,os
for item in sys.argv[2:]:
    os.symlink(sys.argv[1],item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two commands.

```
ln -s Desktop/foo.txt location1; ln -s Desktop/foo.txt location2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ln -s /path/dir/{dir1,dir2,dir3} /path/destination
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will create two links `vi` and `view` for the vim binary with verbose output.

```bash
$ for link in /usr/bin/{vi,view}; do ln -sv /usr/bin/vim $link; done;
'/usr/bin/vi' -> '/usr/bin/vim'
'/usr/bin/view' -> '/usr/bin/vim'
```